# Power Bi : if Condition with multiple cases specially with date = NULL or SYSDATE

Tags: powerbi, tableau-api, powerquery, qlikview, m

I have a table with these columns shipped_date, Promise_date

Example (consider that the current date is today's date which is "20/6/2019"):

```
Shipped_date        Promise_date
20/1/2019           15/1/2019
Null                19/6/2019
Null                25/6/2019
```

How can I make an if condition that gives output

1- `if shipped_date = null and promise_date < today's date then "yes"`

2- `if shipped_date = null and promise_date >= today's date then "no"`

i tried to write Dax code but i succeded in another condition when shipped_date have value and promise_date is not today's date

```
if [JC_ShippedDate] < [PromiseDate] then "Completed early"
else if [JC_ShippedDate] > [PromiseDate] then "Completed behind schedule"
else if [JC_ShippedDate] = [PromiseDate] then "Completed on time" else "open"
```

error is

```
Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value null to type Logical.
Details:
    Value=
    Type=Type
```

Comment: Are you just asking how to get today's date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you are looking for but in DAX, something like this will do the trick:

```
Test =
VAR Today =
    NOW ()
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        AND ( ISBLANK ( 'Table'[Shipped_Date] ), 'Table'[Promise_Date] < Today ), "Yes",
        AND ( ISBLANK ( 'Table'[Shipped_Date] ), 'Table'[Promise_Date] >= Today ), "No",
        'Table'[Shipped_Date] > 'Table'[Promise_Date], "x"
    )
```

After testing on your data I get the following:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot it's working fine but i need also to add If conditions to this code 
eg : if shipped_date > Promise_date then "x"